# Implementing Loading Screens

Tags: c++, loading, wxwidgets, splash-screen

Sometimes it can take a while to load a binary executable.  Applications like GIMP and Code::Blocks have loading screens that pop up almost immediately, and give status messages until the full application is loaded.

How do they get a loading screen to pop up instantaneously and start showing progress before the rest of the application is loaded.

WxWidgets in C++ specific answers are sought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at wxSplashScreen?

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_splash_screen.html

Display this window first, before starting any time consuming initialization.

BTW, if your initialization code is taking a long time to complete, you should probably take a look at its design.

Answer (score 0):

Splash screens are small programs in and of themselves. They load their parent program and then close. You may have noticed (at least for windows) that the splash screen opens a task bar button while loading and then for an instant two will be open then one will close. This is the main program opening and the splash screen program closing.

Comment: There are other ways, using delay loaded dlls.  Also its probably not just binary load time, but I'd guess most splashes also cover application load time.  Otherwise, there'd be no status messages or percentages to show.

Comment: You're overgeneralizing. I don't, personally, know of any program that implements its splash screen as a distinct executable. That's not to say that there aren't such programs out there. Just that they would seem to be the minority. Ultimately, all it boils down to is you call `CreateWindow` (or the equivalent in your framework) before you do any slow operations; then you start pumping messages for the window while you do the rest of the loading. And, finally, when you're done loading, you `DestroyWindow` and show the main UI.

Comment: @NikBougalis Two major examples are Photoshop and Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't see a secondary program that serves as the Visual Studio splash screen. I see *only* `devenv.exe` and *just* verified that the splash screen is shown by the same process as the one that eventually displays the main Visual Studio UI using Spy++. I don't have access to Photoshop, so I can't speak to that conclusively, but again, I see no real point or tangible benefit to having a separate program to serve as a splash screen.